# Working with javascript in VisualStudioCode won't always go to definitaions inside objects with funcitons

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x08T.png)

you can see the comment.

```html
var Main =
{
    AAA: function()
    {
        this.OK = 1;

        this.Foo1 = function()
        {
            this.OK = 2; //says no definition      
        };
    },
};
```

right click on the "this.OK = 2" assignment and select "Go To Definition" will say that there is no definition even though the code will work as it should.
How can I tell intellisense that the "this.OK = 1" line is the definition?

Also I have the same problem in here:

```html
var Main =
{
    OK: 1,

    Foo1: function()
    {
        this.OK = 2; //says no definition      
    },
};
```

@edit:
It will work as it should if I'm using the variable and not assigning a new value to it. example "this.OK.valueOf()" instead of "this.OK = 2". But only in the second example!